# Behaviour of geodesics on surfaces as one of the two endpoints moves slightly

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be two points on a surface (I guess, a Riemann surface) $\Sigma$ such that there is a unique geodesic between $u$ and $v$ on $\Sigma$. Now let $l$ be an arbitrary line that passes through $v$.

1. Is there always a point $v'$ on $l$ such that the geodesic between $u$ and $v'$ is unique?
2. Can we choose $v'$ on $l$ such that if we move $v$ towards $v'$ then the geodesic $u,v$ always remains unique?
3. Can we choose $v'$ on $l$ such that if we move $v$ towards $v'$ then the geodesic $u,v$ deforms continuously until it is the same as the geodesic $u,v'$?

I believe the answer to all the above questions is: yes, choose $v'$ to be a point that is located close enough to $v$. However, I do not know the reason behind it. I would appreciate if you can point out any relevant references.

Comment: This should be fairly obvious if you lift to the universal cover. You should just need to think a little about the geometry of the fundamental domain, which is a finite-sided polygon.

Comment: Look up the definitions of `cut locus' and `conjugate locus'.  Cheeger and Ebin are a good source.  Assume that $\nu$ lies within the domain $U = exp_{u} (V),  V \subset T_u \Sigma$ , $V$ star-shaped such that $exp_u$ is a diffeo.  As long as your $\nu'$ varies in this $V$ what you want works perfectly, regardless of the dimension of $\Sigma$.